# How to send photos with self-destruct timer using Telegram Bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In the Telegram app, you can send photos that self-destruct and can't be screenshotted by clicking on the clock icon before sending them. Is there any way to reproduce this behavior using the Telegram Bot API?

I'm using python-telegram-bot and couldn't find anything in its docs, but i'm not even sure if the API allows it. I could delete the messages after some time using `bot.delete_message`, however, the important part here is that the images shouldn't be screenshottable.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using python-telegram-bot and couldn't find anything in docs, but i'm not even sure if the API allows it.

Telegram Bot API does not support such method yet.

> I could delete the messages after some time using bot.delete_message, however, the important part here is that the images shouldn't be screenshottable.

Yes, bot can delete messages "manually" but there's no way to control the ability of making screenshots.

Comment: I see, thank you! I suppose I'll go ahead and try using `telegram-cli` alongside my bot to send secret photos. If it works, I'll add it later as an answer.